# Filepicker and s3 without revealing s3 secretkey to filepicker

Tags: amazon-s3, filepicker.io, filepicker

Is it possible to use filepicker to upload to S3, using a presigned S3 policy, without revealing my s3 secret key to filepicker.

From their current documentation found here - https://developers.filepicker.io/page/s3/, we need to provide them our s3 secret key.

I know s3 supports browser based uploads using POST, which we can sign using the policy. Is this something filepicker can leverage?

Answer (score 1):

While it is technically possible, the Filepicker system does not work in this way. We require your S3 keys in order to upload to S3.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Andrew. How is it possible to do it, as you say it is?